# How can I use clk as an input port in Verilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I am working on a simple FSM that counts to 3 and will either output 1 or 0 based on if the number of times a 1 is counted on is mod3 = 0.

FSM.sv

```
module FSM (input logic in, clk,
            output logic out);

    reg [1:0] state;
    reg [1:0] w;
    
    initial
        state = 2'b00;

    //state change logic
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        case({state,in})
        {2'b0,1'b0}:
            w = 2'b00;
        {2'b0,1'b1}:
            w = 2'b01;
        {2'b1,1'b0}:
            w = 2'b01;
        {2'b1,1'b1}:
            w = 2'b10;
        {2'b10,1'b0}:
            w = 2'b10;
        {2'b10,1'b1}:
            w = 2'b00;
        endcase
    end
    
    always @(w)
        state = w;

    //update output based on state
    always @(negedge clk) begin
        
        case(state)
            2'b00: out = 1'b1;
            2'b01: out = 1'b0;
            2'b10: out = 1'b0;
        endcase

    end
    
endmodule
```

FSM_tb.sv

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module tb ();

   logic     in;
   logic     out;
   logic     clk;   
   
  // instantiate device under test
   FSM dut (in, out, clk);

   // 2 ns clock
   initial 
     begin  
    clk = 1'b1;
    forever #10 clk = ~clk;
     end


   initial
     begin
    
    #0      in = 1'b0;
    
    #20     in = 1'b1;
    
    #20     in = 1'b0;
    
    #20     in = 1'b1;
    
    #20     in = 1'b0;
    
    #20     in = 1'b1;
    
     end

   
endmodule
```

You can see that in my FSM.sv file I am checking the input and current state at the posedge of the clock which is an input to the module. When it is the negedge of the clock it will update the output based on the state.

My issue is that in my FSM_tb.sv you can see I am trying to set the clk to a cycle of 20ns and it gives the error in Modelsim console of:

```
Variable '/tb/clk', driven via a port connection, is multiply driven.
```

If I remove the clk from my FSM.sv file it will remove the error, but obviously my posedge/negedge blocks will no longer function. How am I supposed to correctly use the clk within a module?

Comment: A clock signal is used as a port rather than a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your port connections are out of position.

Try

```
FSM dut (in, clk, out); // positional
```

or

```
FSM dut (.in, .out, .clk); // by .name
```

or

```
FSM dut (.*); // match all by name
```

Also, your test runs *forever*. Put a `#20 $finish` at the end of your last `initial` block.